# Ruby zlib deflate massive data

Tags: ruby, zlib, compression, deflate

I'm trying to use Zlib::Deflate.deflate on a massive file (4 gigs).  There are obvious problems with doing that, the first of which being that I can't load the entire file into  memory all at once.  Zlib::GzipWriter would work, since it works with streams, but it's not zlib compression.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try instantiating a Zlib::Deflate stream and feeding it data from your big file piecemeal. Zlib::Deflate::deflate purports to do that sort of thing behind the scenes.

It would look something like this:

```
z = Zlib::Deflate.new

File.open "big_uncompressed_file" do |f|
  File.open "big_compressed_file", "w" do |w|
    f.each do |str|
      w << z.deflate str, Zlib::SYNC_FLUSH
    end
  end
end
z.finish
z.close
```

[ruby zlib docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/index.html)

[notes on zlib flush flags](http://www.bolet.org/~pornin/deflate-flush.html)

Comment: Zlib by itself does work incrementally in this way - you give it buffers of data incrementally and it spits out compressed data.

Comment: You'd want the output of finish at the end of your big_compressed_file ("w").

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells i.e. `w << z.deflate(str, Zlib::NO_FLUSH)` ? @toothrot i.e. `f.write(z.finish)` ?